# Console printing different text font swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

I have set different font for my `textField` and it is working fine. I can enter a gujarati font into my `textField` this way I set font:

[image]

But when I try to print user's text it's printing english letters. Suppose I enter into `textField` like `અબચ` but it prints `Optional("abc")` into console so I tried to use `attributedString` but it gives me same result and below is my code:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "HARIKRISHNA", size: 16) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: userText!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
        print(attributedString.string)
    } else {
        // The font "Raleway-SemiBold" is not found
        print("The font Raleway-SemiBold is not found")

    }
```

Is there any way to log output in same language of `textField`?

[Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06703428613397777419) for more Info.

Comment: Yes. I want same log as user entered into textField. @EICaptain

Comment: You can change the console font in Xcode preferences > Fonts & Colors

Comment: I am want to use that text for search into search controller.

Comment: @EICaptain Unless the font is inaccessible via the font inspector, OP should be able to select his font. He managed to change the font of the text field, therefore should also be able to change the console font to that same one.

Comment: The console uses a fixed font which you cannot change programmatically. `print(textF.attributedText!)` would print a "textual representation" including the attributes. But what is your *actual problem* with the search controller?

Comment: When I enter something into search bar it shows me gujarati text but my all data is in gujarati language so search is not working. because it can not find that text entered by user but if i use gujarati keyboard it is working fine. But I want this with english keyboard. And thanks for your response.. :)@MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode console window uses a font which can be changed in the Xcode
preferences, but not programmatically at runtime.
The `print()` function writes a "textual representation" of the
given arguments. For a `String`, this is just the string itself:

```
print(textF.text!)
// Output:
abc
```

For an attributed string, the textual representation is a description
containing the string and attributes:

```
print(textF.attributedText!)
// Output:
abc{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa6984241f0> font-family: \"HARIKRISHNA\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 2, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}";
}
```

Your *actual* problem seems to be a different one. Assigning a special
font to a text field changes only the appearance of the string,
not the characters in the string itself.

So if the user enters `"abc"` then `textF.text` is `"abc"`, even if you
have a font which *displays* that as `"અબચ"`. Therefore matching that
string against `"અબચ"` cannot work.

I do not have experience with the Gujarati language to propose a good
solution. It might be interesting to know that you can "transliterate"
foreign languages to the Latin alphabet (from http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/):

```
let text = "અબચ" as NSMutableString
CFStringTransform(text, nil, kCFStringTransformToLatin, false)
print(text)
```

The result is "abaca" because

```
અ = GUARATI LETTER A
બ = GUARATI LETTER BA
ચ = GUARATI LETTER CA
```

But I don't know if that helps in your real application.

Comment: Is there any way to convert `abc` to `અબચ` as I am trying with `NSMutableAttributedString` in my question? So I can use it for search.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni: As I said, you convert only the *attributes*, not the string itself. "a" and "અ" are different characters. If there is a one-to-one correspondence from the Gujarati to the Latin alphabet then you could map each character using a fixed dictionary.